# Laravel - Share variable in route group

Tags: laravel

I have a route group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'item'], function() {
    Route::post('{item}/add-image', [
        'as' => 'store_image_path',
        'uses' => 'ProductController@postImage',

    ]);

    Route::post('{item}/update-image', [
       'as' => 'update_image_path',
        'uses' => 'ProductController@updateImage',
    ]);
});
```

As you see, all route have the first parameter as `{item}`and now i have to add another route that start again with this parameter.

There is a way to specify this just one time and "share" the information to all routes in a group ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'item/{item}'], function () {

    Route::get('/add-image', [
        'as' => 'store_image_path',
        'uses' => 'ProductController@postImage',
    ]);

    Route::get('/update-image', [
        'as' => 'update_image_path',
        'uses' => 'ProductController@updateImage',
    ]);

});
```

Try this. You can add {item} to prefix. 
Then, the paths will be `'item/{item}/add-image'` and `'item/{item}/update-image'`.

Whatever you add routes within that group, routes will be start with '`item/{item}`'.